# How to set orientation of DataTemplate generated buttons?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I attached the picture which exactly describes my problem. I am wpf beginner, maybe i just dont know what tags are the most suitable for this purpose.

[image]

My whole XAML code, i set horizontal orientation everywhere possible, but those buttons are unfortunatelly generated vertically anyway.

```
<Window x:Class="EnterEventTextBox.DataView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EnterEventTextBox"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Black"
        Title="DataView" 
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" Background="Turquoise"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="ItemsControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Shippers}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" Style="{DynamicResource ItemsControlStyle1}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <WrapPanel Background="Green" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ToggleButton Height="50" Width="50" Background="Red" Content="{Binding BtnLabelShipper}" IsChecked="{Binding IsUnrolled}" Margin="0,0,5,5" 
                                cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action ShipperIsClicked($dataContext, $this.IsChecked)]">
                        </ToggleButton>

                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parcels}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Button}">
  <!-- THIS BUTTONS LOWER I NEED CREATE IN A HORIZONTAL WAY --> 
                                    <Button Height="50" Width="50" Background="Red" Content="{Binding ParcelNumber}" Margin="0,0,5,5"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>

                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I suspect the parent control of wrap panel is restricting max width that is available to wrap panel, hence even if it is trying to place contents horizontally, there is not enough width to lay them and hence they are overflowing into new row

you may wanna try changing WrapPanel to StackPanel and see if that is the case, if so, you can provide unrestricted width from parent.

Comment: The inner ItemsControl uses its default ItemsPanel, i.e. a vertically oriented StackPanel.

Comment: plus you haven't applied ItemsControltyle1 to your item control

Comment: Clemens: Your answear is solution
Muds: Style only belongs to first ItemsControl, and it is applied correctly. But thanks for your effort too, i appreciate your effort and wilingness a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for other people who could deal with this problem too.

Into < Window.Resources> insert this:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsStackPanelTemplate1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" Background="Violet"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

And add this template to (inner one) ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parcels}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsStackPanelTemplate1}">
```

---

You also do not have to use a resource declaration. This works as well:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parcels}">
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Violet"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: As a note, using DynamicResource isn't actually required here (it could as well be StaticResource), as well as declaring a resource at all.